# Как общаться с JSON-RPC средствами php?

Tags: json, php

Как общаться с JSON-RPC средствами php?

Answer (score 2):

Существует большое количество *готовых* реализаций как серверной так и клиентской частей JSON RPC на PHP. Например, https://github.com/fguillot/JsonRPC.

Еще несколько реализаций перечислены на странице https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON-RPC#Implementations. А еще можно спросить у Google (`json rpc php implementation`).

Answer (score 1):

а в чем проблема ? в общем случае это:

```
$sendData = array(
    'p1' => 'v1',
    'p2' => 'v2',
....
);

function request($endPointUrlApi, $sendData)
{
    $ch = curl_init($endPointUrlApi);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($sendData));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
    $out = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return json_decode($out, true);
}
```